# springboot oauth access token validation with user details before api call

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

i am working on springboot architecture with oauth security.
And we have authorization server and resource server.
All are working fine.

Here we need to authorize user on every api call.

**The issue scenario is -we hit the api with user1 accesstoken,but we are able to get the user2 information with the same user1 access token.**

It will reduce security for the user information.

So how can we handle this scenario?
where we need to configure this setttings for validate the accesstoken with the corresponding user?

We need a solution like

**user1 accesstoken only able to get the user1 information,not able to get the user2 information..**

Thanks,

Arunraj M

Answer (score 0):

Spring security provides only method level authorities, for example if you have a method called getAllUsers(), and for the user you have created a token have access to this method should able to get all the user details.

If you want to filter further, then implement JWTtokens and from the token you can get the user for which the token is been generated, from that you can write a filter to get a appropriate value